# Woocommerce: limit user to see only the products he created

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, author

I have this code where the authors can see only own posts. I need the authors to see only the products they have created on woocommerce. I know the woocommerce products have no authors by default, but I can add this with a plugin. Whats I want to do is to change this snippet to limit the lists of products in the custom post type of woocommerce.

Someone know the best way to do that?

Thanks!

```
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
        global $pagenow;

    if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
        return $query;

    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
       global $user_ID;
       $query->set('author', $user_ID );
     }
     return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe changing the following conditional:

```
if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
```

to this one:

```
if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && 'product' === $query->get( 'post_type' ) )
```

would do it.

Brief explanation: I added a second condition which checks if the query is for WooCommerce products where the post type is `product`.

### UPDATE

If you want to make certain that the code runs only on the products page (WooCommerce → Products), then you can (remove the `global $pagenow;` and) change this:

```
if( 'edit.php' != $pagenow || !$query->is_admin )
```

to this one:

```
if( !$query->is_admin || 'edit-product' !== get_current_screen()->id )
```

And instead of relying on the global `$user_ID`, you should probably use `get_current_user_id()`: `$query->set( 'author', get_current_user_id() );` :)